# Instance has been deleted error after commit

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, replication, database-replication

I am using **sqlachemy** in my python project. I have a Read-Write replication setup on MYSQL database and I am redirecting all Select queries on Read instance and all other on Write using RoutingSession class as given below :

```
# create engine
engines = {
    "read": create_engine(readConnectionString, convert_unicode=True, poolclass=NullPool,isolation_level="READ UNCOMMITTED", pool_recycle = 800),
    "write": create_engine(writeConnectionString, convert_unicode=True, poolclass=NullPool,isolation_level="READ UNCOMMITTED", pool_recycle = 800)
}

class RoutingSession(Session):     
    def get_bind(self, mapper=None, clause=None):  
        if isinstance(clause, (Select)):
            return engines["read"]
        else:
            return engines["write"]
                
Session = sessionmaker(class_=RoutingSession, autocommit=False, autoflush=True)
db_session = scoped_session(Session)
```

Everything is working fine, it is routing all Select queries on Read engine and all other on Write engine. But sometimes when we write anything using db_session.commit() and try to get any column from the instance after commit it gives and error like this

```
UserObj = User(None, userName, userContact)
db_session.add(UserObj)
db_session.commit()
print(User.userId)  #just print Primary Key of last insert

Got this error
**Instance '<User at 0x7fdaf22fffa0>' has been deleted, or its row is otherwise not present**
```

While we check log using echo we found that a select is executed after commit and which routed to Read engine and give this error. Not sure how to handle such situation ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By default, instances are expired after a commit, so if their attributes are accessed a `SELECT ` will be emitted. You can set `expire_on_commit=False` on the session, if you don't mind having potentially stale data in memory. Or you could flush the session and access the `id` before committing.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Tried expire_on_commit=False but it still comes randomly

Comment: Also being discussed on GitHub [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/10233)